# Role of monotonicity in sequences of bounded variation.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Recall that; A sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ of real numbers is said to be of bounded variation if the eries
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left|x_{k}-x_{k-1}\right|
$$
Converges.

We know that convergent sequence need not be a sequence of bounded variation by taking $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for even $n$ and $0$ for odd $n$. But what about monotone convergent sequences? Are they sequence of bounded variation? If so, how to prove that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $\{x_n\}$ is increasing,

$$\sum_{k=2}^n |x_k - x_{k-1}| = \sum_{k=2}^n x_k - x_{k-1} = x_n - x_1.$$